# Find nth file/folder in QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using a QFileSystemModel and a QTreeView and I am trying to make the TreeView select the first folder/file by default. To do that I need to get the index of the first folder/file but I can't find a method that does that in QFileSystemModel.

Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

---

I have tried `setCurrentIndex(_model->index(x, y))` but it didn't work. Here's the code I have and the tree shown:

```
void CodeView::finished_loading(QString file) {
        qDebug()<<"Currently selected : " << _model->fileName( ui->treeView->currentIndex());
        qDebug()<<"(0,0) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(0,0));
        qDebug()<<"(1,0) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(1,0));
        qDebug()<<"(2,0) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(2,0));
        qDebug()<<"(3,0) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(3,0));
        qDebug()<<"(0,0) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(0,0));
        qDebug()<<"(1,1) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(1,1));
        qDebug()<<"(2,1) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(2,1));
        qDebug()<<"(3,1) "<< _model->fileName(_model->index(3,1));
        ui->treeView->setCurrentIndex(_model.index(1,0));
        qDebug()<<"New selected : " << _model->fileName( ui->treeView->currentIndex());
}
```

Output :

```
Currently selected :  "Wassim Gharbi"
(0,0)  "/"
(1,0)  ""
(2,0)  ""
(3,0)  ""
(0,0)  "/"
(1,1)  ""
(2,1)  ""
(3,1)  ""
New selected :  "Wassim Gharbi"
```

[image: Tree]

Comment: The second argument in `model->index(x, y)` does NOT stand for child items. It actually stands for the columns of an item like date modified, file size, name, etc.

Please see my answer for how to get the child index of a parent index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is not in the model, but in the view.

```
 QTreeView::setCurrentIndex
```

from the docs:

> QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex(const QModelIndex &index) Sets the
>   current item to be the item at index.
>
> Unless the current selection mode is NoSelection, the item is also
>   selected. Note that this function also updates the starting position
>   for any new selections the user performs.
>
> To set an item as the current item without selecting it, call
>
> selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(index,
>   QItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate);
>
> See also currentIndex(), currentChanged(), and selectionMode.

The code for the first folder is not really easy as first glance but you need to remember that the data abstractions on the models makes it powerfull, and cumberstone at the same time, so any item could potentially be a folder or a file, and we need to check for that:

```
if (model->rowCount()) // has at least one file or folder
{
   QModelIndex current = model->index(0,0);
   if (model->rowCount(current) == 0); // it's a file.
      return current;
   else {
      // walk the tree trying to find the first file on the folders.
      while(model->rowCount(current) > 0) {
          current = model->index(0,0,current);
      }
      if (index.isValid())
         return index; // our file inside folders
      else 
         return QModelIndex(); // no file inside folders.
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick response. Actually, I do not care whether it is a file or a folder, I just want to select the first item in the tree.  Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: His answer is overcomplicating things. He is doing the same as calling `QModelIndex::child()` by calling `QStandardItemModel::index(row, column, parentIndex)`. And where exactly is he returning to? Also you said you don't care about the item's type?

Comment: it's implicit that this was inside a function call, at least I tougth it was implicit. :) and he said (before editing (I wanna have the first file, since the first file could be inside a chain of folders, it was the quickest solution I could think of.).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the index at a specific location in the model, use `QModelIndex::child(row, column)`

```
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel();
model->setRootPath("C:/Qt");//your path

ui->treeView->setModel(model);
ui->treeView->setCurrentIndex(model->index(0, 0).child(0, 0));
```

I can tell from your question that you don't understand how a treeview's row and column system works. Please read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-classes)

Comment: Please see the updated question, `idx.child(0,0)` doesn't really work...

Comment: I edited my answer. Since you didn't set a root index, you can still call `QModelIndex::child()` from the index at `model->index(0, 0)`

I can tell from your question that you don't understand how a treeview's row and column system works. Please read the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-classes